# How to set the the key:cust_key while using REST API V1 for Messaging

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We are using a REST API to trigger an email, using [Customer Key POST : Messaging](https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:cust_key/send).

So while sending the mail we wanted to set different subject for different scenario. Few key was created and provided for us and we have been using that but if we wanted to set the subject line dynamically for email then is there any way to do it?

Comment: Your link is directing to a 403 page can you please post a copy of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple of different methods for this scenario and here are the steps involved:

**METHOD 1**

- Create a field in the Data Extension that holds the subject line. for eg: **subjectLine**
- Now in your API Payload you need to add an attribute for subject line. for eg:

  {
      "From": {
          "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
          "Name": "Code@"
      },
      "To": {
          "Address": "example@example.com",
          "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
          "ContactAttributes": {
              "SubscriberAttributes": {
                  "subjectLine": "Here is the subject line",
                  "FName": "John",
                  "LName": "Citizen"
              }
          }
      }
  }
- Then in your subject line you can reference %%subjectLine%% to bring dynamic subject line.

**METHOD 2**

It really depends on the data type for eg JSON or XML you're passing on in an attribute. Then you will parse that data to the email, next thing is to set that subject line to a AMPScript variable and then use that variable in the subject line.

I prefer the first option as you can pass the subject line directly to the email rather than parsing within the email body and setting it to a variable and then passing it to the subject line.

Comment: I have created field as subjectLine in the DataExtension. while calling the ExactTarget Api i am passing the data to it. Now how it will map to the email Subject, because it can go as email body as well. Is there any way that exactTarget determine which value will be set to Email Subject.

Comment: @JigmeSherab Can you see subjectline text populated in your DE after the API request? If yes then you can just wrap %%subjecline_DE_Field%% in AMPScript quotes and put it in the email subject part.